# Azure / R-server - head causes process to hang

Tags: r, azure, revoscaler, r-server

I'm trying to use the `head` command for an hdfs data set in Azure using R-server via RStudio.  This has worked in the past but in the last 2 days it seems like it's stopped working.  When I execute it, it tells me the process has started running but never prints anything.

`rxGetInfo` seems to work fine on the same data.  Any ideas to check why this is happening?